# H2+ ion: Which Hamiltonian matrix elements vanish based on symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry

Using only 1s, 2s, and 2p orbitals, which of the matrix elements $H_{kl} = \int \chi_k \hat{H} \chi_l d\tau$ (where H is the full molecular Hamiltonian and $\chi_i$ are the atomic orbitals eg. 1s AO of H-atom) vanish based only on symmetry arguments without needing a calculation?

Will the integral vanish if you have for example a $p_x$ and a $p_y$ orbital where the z-axis is the molecular axis, because you have minimal overlap of the AOs?

Comment: I see you're new to the site. If you find any answer helpful to you, please [upvote](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) or [accept](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hydrogen molecule and its various ions fall into the $D_{\infty\mathrm{h}}$ [point group](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3438).

For an integral to be non-zero, the product of its components must contain the totally symmetric irreducible representation (irrep) under said point group, which here is $\mathrm{A_{1g}}$. $s$-orbitals are perfectly spherical, so they always transform as the totally symmetric irrep. $p_x$ and $p_y$ both transform as $\mathrm{E_{1u}}$, and $p_z$ transforms as $\mathrm{A_{1u}}$. [The non-relativistic molecular Hamiltonian is invariant to all these symmetry operations](https://books.google.com/books?id=oIzuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=molecular+hamiltonian+symmetry&source=bl&ots=OpB1nQTyDG&sig=BbAIa1W3_woRoDOPx497_yqfrb4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO0Lu8-8TQAhVJJCYKHYtkDocQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=molecular%20hamiltonian%20symmetry&f=false), so it too transforms as $\mathrm{A_{1g}}$.

To determine the final product, refer to a [direct product table](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/group-theory-tables#3442). The product of any irrep with itself will always give the totally symmetric irrep. So, for example, if your $\{\chi\}$ are both $p_x$ orbitals, the integral will not vanish due to symmetry arguments. In general, if your $\{\chi\}$ are different, because the product of different irreps never contains the fully symmetric irrep, those integrals will be zero.

However, due to $p_x$ and $p_y$ transforming identically, matrix elements between them don't necessarily vanish. In the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian in the atomic orbital basis, these rules will lead to a diagonal matrix, except for a block corresponding to $p_x$ and $p_y$.